# Merging two results from sql to echo on php

Tags: php, mysql, web-services

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM election WHERE election_date >= NOW() ORDER BY election_date LIMIT 1");
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT has_voted from users where pid = 3");

$results = array();
$line1 = mysql_fetch_object($result2);
while($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $results[] = $line;
}

array_push($results, $line1);
echo (json_encode($results));
```

That is my php code, what I want here is to output the two sql results as one. Below is the output that I will get when echoing the result.

```
[
{
election_id: "3",
election_title: "",
election_date: "2016/02/20",
start_time: "08:00",
end_time: "23:59",
election_venue: "",
status: "0",
num_needed: "3"
},
{
has_voted: "1"
}
]
```

As you can see, the `has_voted: "1"` is separated from the first one. Is it possible for me to include that result to the first one? So the output that I want is this:

```
[
{
election_id: "3",
election_title: "",
election_date: "2016/02/20",
start_time: "08:00",
end_time: "23:59",
election_venue: "",
status: "0",
num_needed: "3"
has_voted: "1"
}
]
```

I have tried using the array_merge() and this is my code:

`$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM election WHERE election_date >= NOW() ORDER BY election_date LIMIT 1");
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT has_voted from users where pid = 3");`

`$results = array();
$results1 = array();`

`while($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $results[] = $line;
}
while($line1 = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $results1[] = $line1;`
}`

`$final = array_merge($results, $results1);
echo (json_encode($final));`

The output is still not the one I wanted:

`[
{
election_id: "3",
election_title: "",
election_date: "2016/02/20",
start_time: "08:00",
end_time: "23:59",
election_venue: "",
status: "0",
num_needed: "3"
},
{
has_voted: "1"
}
]`

Comment: Have you heard about Union Operator:- http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*`API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: you can use `array_merge($results, $line1)`

Comment: @Plum yep, I have tried using union but unfortunately it's giving me error due to column count.

Comment: Why are you using two separate queries? Can't you use a join here?

Comment: @PathikVejani I have tried that as well but it's not showing the `has_voted`

Comment: have you followed my answer? @fmpsagara

Comment: @codeHeart they are totally different tables. I just want to output the results as one.

Comment: @PathikVejani yeah but it's not working :(

Comment: @fmpsagara post your both of array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `array_merge($line,$line1);`
Then output will be

```
Array ( [election_id] => 3 [election_title] => [election_date] => 2016/02/20 [start_time] => 08:00 [end_time] => 23:59 [election_venue] => [status] => 0 [num_needed] => 3 [has_voted] => 1 )
```

Comment: woah! for some reasons it's giving me the correct results now!

Answer (score 2):

Use [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$finalArr = array_merge($results, $line1);
echo json_encode($finalArr);
```

Comment: `$results = array();
$results1 = array();

while($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $results[] = $line;
}
while($line1 = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $results1[] = $line1;
}

$final = array_merge($results, $results1);
echo (json_encode($final));`
The output is:
`[{
election_id: "3",
election_title: "",
election_date: "2016/02/20",
start_time: "08:00",
end_time: "23:59",
election_venue: "",
status: "0",
num_needed: "3"
},
{
has_voted: "1"
}
]`